# Add additional product price with mangento base product price

Tags: magento, product

I want to add additional price with product(simple) price, I am trying to do this with the help of custom attributes. I add a custom attribute "Margin Price" and I want to add up this custom attribute value (margin price) with the base price of the product in the template file.

I am updating all product price after each 5 minutes by cron job, thats why I think I have to do add margin price with base product price by this way.

I added it successfully in product list page and in product view page, but have problem with how to add this margin price with base price in the cart and onepage checkout?

Here is the code on the product list page and same for the product detail page which works fine for me in magento 1.6.x.

```
$regularPrice = number_format($_product->getFinalPrice(), 2); 
 //echo $regularPrice =  $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true 
$priceWithoutComma = str_replace(",", "",$regularPrice);
settype($priceWithoutComma, "float");
$marPrice = $_product->getMarginPrice();
settype($marPrice, "integer");
$finalPrice = $priceWithoutComma + $marPrice;
echo $finalPrice.Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->
getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol();
```

I am doing this right way or I have to changes the whole process?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might need to consider a different approach. The reason being that echoing the price from a template file does not modify the price of the item in any way. It simply outputs a calculation.

You'll need to learn a bit about event listeners for this one to work.

[Here's a blog post of mine on how to do this.](http://mikebywaters.wordpress.com/2012/03/30/add-an-item-to-the-cart-with-a-custom-price-in-magento/)

Comment: Thanks! Actually I did it another way that I added margin price with price which I am getting from another website, So, every time it override the base price. But the margin price will be taken from our database.